# How can i use the values of serial.readline() function in python

Tags: python, arduino

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMO',9600)
while 1:
      ser.readline()
```

I am getting output of my sensors on python like

```
X=316 O=418
```

can you help me to use these values 316 and 418?

Comment: Use them for what? You want to assign the result of `ser.readline()` to a variable, and probably parse it in some way (but it's hard to say in what way without knowing the possible text you might get back from the serial port...)

Comment: i want to use them for controlling mt mouse...how can i give condition  like if my x range is between 315 to 333 than move my mouse pointer to a specific point...i want to access them to control my mouse pointer

Comment: to control your mouse, if you're using Xorg, you need to look at [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net), I think that's your best bet to have it controlled.

Comment: can i use a variable i have seen a code for a temprature sensor which is plotting the values coming from arduino to raspberry pi he has accessed the variable of incoming values but what if i have more values than one sensor... import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
try:
 while 1:
  line=ser.readline().rstrip()
  temp2=line
  print("%s"%(temp2))
  f=open('tempLog.dat','a')
  print >>f,("%s"%(temp2))
  f.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print "\ndone"

Answer (score 0):

do you want the following?

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMO',9600)
while 1:
      x_value, o_value = ser.readline().split(" ")
      x_value = x_value.split("=")[-1]
      o_value = o_value.split("=")[-1]
      print o_value, x_value
```

> ValueError: empty separator

Well, it usually means you're parsing a line that does not match the splits we're trying to do, you may want to try this instead:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMO',9600)
while 1:
      value = ser.readline().split(" ")
      if " " in value:
      x_value, o_value = value
      if "=" in x_value and "=" in o_value:
          x_value = x_value.split("=")[-1]
          o_value = o_value.split("=")[-1]
          print o_value, x_value
      else:
          print value
```

Comment: thank you sir for the reply.. but i am getting error while runnig code that..
ValueError: empty separator
please help me...thank you again

Comment: Sir last help it is showing error too many values to unpack sir please last help....thank you